# typescript omit remove unwanted properties

Tags: typescript

I havve the following types:

```js
type A = {
    role: 'admin',
    force?: boolean
}

type B = {
    role: 'regular'
}

type Req = { data: number } & (A | B);
```

When when I do some manipulation on `Req` `force` is removed for some reason:

```js
type NoData = Omit<Req, 'data'>;

const noData: NoData = {
    role: 'admin',
    force: true
}
```

and I get:

```
Type '{ role: "admin"; force: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'NoData'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'force' does not exist in type 'NoData'.(2322)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oCcD2AbCAXFAOQCGAJgLYCWAdsQDRoYBm2mAxhAPxEBG2PBFK0UAXxQpQkKACEEyZuhz4ixTBADmAV1ylMxcZOnQA8pgVIo5UsFJFa2ynwgWxUAGRQAFHAA%20cgCUANzG4NAActgAIrakCqY0wAA85gwkNnbEAHyhKBzYtADOwFC0MXFEUbF2lkpYQmoUNPRMGFBsnIRQwJjaEEaSQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default version of`Omit` is not distributive, meaning it will apply to the union as a whole, or more specific to the common properties of the union, rather than to each constituent of the union

You can create a distributive version using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) :

```
type A = {
    role: 'admin',
    force?: boolean
}

type B = {
    role: 'regular'
}

type Or = { data: number } & (A | B);
type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends T ? Omit<T, K> : never;
type NoData = DistributiveOmit<Or, 'data'>;

const noData: NoData = {
    role: 'admin',
    force: true
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oCcD2AbCAXFAOQCGAJgLYCWAdsQDRoYBm2mAxhAPxEBG2PBFK0UAXxQpQkKACEEyZuhz4ixTBADmAV1ylMxcZOnQA8pgVIo5UsFJFa2ynwgWxUAGRQAFHAA+cgCUANxS4NAAItQAzsCY1HzawNQAbhCmNMAAPAAqDFAA0lAQAB7AELTk0VAACjiQmKAFECAAfAo5xWUVVVCd3FAZ1Nl5he0OEGmYoSZQAHLYEbakClGx8YnJaUPZ5vnENnbEraEoHNi0sVC0i8tEC0t2lkpYQmoUNPRMGFBsnIRQOLaCBGSRAA)